# Indifference between gaussian or binomial error distribution with categorical predictors

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, interaction, binomial-distribution

When modeling a percentage outcome from two categorical predictors, the error family choice should be binomial or quasibinomial as far as I know.
For prediction the choice does not make even the slightest difference, and I don't understand why. Can anybody here help me understand this?

I wanted in this model to include interactions, and as far as I can see it does not make sense to include main effects as well, when I only model the interactions between to categoricals. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Update:** I think I figured it out. When fitting a model with only interactions of the categorical like this, I am actually just fitting means for the outcome of all unique combinations of the predictors. Since a mean of values between 0 and 100 cannot be negative the gaussian and binomial outcome will actually be the same. Am I right?

```
> a <-  c(0,  0, 0, 0,  0,   1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, 1,   2,  0,   1,  2)
> b <-  c(1,  2, 0, 1,  2,   0,  1,  1,  2,  2,  0,  0,  1,  2,  0, 2,   1,  1,   0,  1)
> y <-  c(0, 10, 0, 0, 20, 100, 50, 60, 30, 80, 40, 30, 20, 30, 50, 90, 10, 10, 100, 20)
> 
> a <- as.factor(a)
> b <- as.factor(b)
> y <- y/100
> 
> m1 <- glm(y ~ a : b + 0, family = gaussian)
> summary(m1)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ a:b + 0, family = gaussian)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.3667  -0.0375   0.0000   0.0500   0.2333  

Coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a0:b0  0.00000    0.15076   0.000 1.000000    
a1:b0  1.00000    0.10660   9.381 1.39e-06 ***
a2:b0  0.40000    0.08704   4.596 0.000770 ***
a0:b1  0.03333    0.08704   0.383 0.709039    
a1:b1  0.55000    0.10660   5.159 0.000314 ***
a2:b1  0.16667    0.08704   1.915 0.081864 .  
a0:b2  0.15000    0.10660   1.407 0.187012    
a1:b2  0.66667    0.08704   7.659 9.85e-06 ***
a2:b2  0.30000    0.15076   1.990 0.072030 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.02272727)

    Null deviance: 4.89  on 20  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.25  on 11  degrees of freedom
AIC: -10.883

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> m2 <- glm(y ~ a : b + 0, family = quasibinomial)
> summary(m2)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ a:b + 0, family = quasibinomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.74807  -0.15839   0.00002   0.10931   0.54717  

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
a0:b0  -20.5661  6159.7468  -0.003   0.9974  
a1:b0   20.5661  4355.5987   0.005   0.9963  
a2:b0   -0.4055     0.4094  -0.990   0.3433  
a0:b1   -3.3673     1.1174  -3.014   0.0118 *
a1:b1    0.2007     0.4938   0.406   0.6923  
a2:b1   -1.6094     0.5382  -2.990   0.0123 *
a0:b2   -1.7346     0.6880  -2.521   0.0284 *
a1:b2    0.6931     0.4255   1.629   0.1316  
a2:b2   -0.8473     0.7581  -1.118   0.2875  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 0.1206952)

    Null deviance: 11.9922  on 20  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  1.3688  on 11  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19

> 
> all.equal(predict(m1), predict(m2, type = "response"))
[1] TRUE
```